# Matrix made up by $2$ orthonormal vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $y$ is transposed

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank, orthonormal, transpose

I came across the following exercise from my professor and had no idea how to start. I tried it with the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, which results in a rank of $1$ and eigenvalue $0$, but this must be shown without an example using an explanation of different properties. The literal question can be found below:

Given two orthonormal vectors x, y in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
Consider the matrix $A = xy^T$.

- What is the rank of A, and what does it tell you about the eigenvalues?
- Calculate $A^2$ and deduce what the eigenvalues of $A$ are.

Note: I do not want to see an example, not even with vectors and matrices with letters!

Comment: Hint: $A^2 = (xy^T)(xy^T) = x(y^Tx)y^T$. Now use that $y$ and $x$ are orthonormal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $x_i=\langle x,e_i\rangle$ for $e_1,e_2$ the standard basis, and the same for $y$. As $x,y$ are orthogonal, we know that $x_1y_1 +x_2y_2 = 0$. Note that $M=(x_iy_j)_{i,j}$ in the standard basis. Computing the characteristic polynomial, we see that
$$ \chi(\lambda) = \lambda^2-\lambda(x_1y_1+x_2y_2)+x_1x_2y_1y_2-x_1x_2y_1y_2 = \lambda^2$$
using the equality above. We see that the only eigenvalue is $0$, thus the matrix must have rank $1$ or $0$. It is easy to check that $M$ being the zero matrix implies that either $x$ or $y$ is the zero vector, which is not possible. Thus it has rank $1$.

Edit: Following @Stiftungwarentest 's hint provides a much shorter and cleaner proof.

Comment: I think I understand but there is one more step I don't understand from your answer. Why does $-\lambda (x_{1}y_{1} + x_{2}y_{2})$ disappear in the equation?

Comment: @MaximDecherf Because $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal, i.e. $x_1y_1+x_2y_2=0$, as I wrote in my first line.